# How to flash a div only

Tags: html, css

Can I flash a div using only CSS? I would like this div to flash two colors.

```
.chat-window .msg-container-base .notification-message-unread{
  float: right;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #666;
  background: white;
  padding-left: 10px; 
}
```

Comment: Create animation using css `@keyframes`

Comment: do you need it to continue flashing between the two colors without stopping?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768706/css3-animation-change-continuously

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go:

```css
.notification-message-unread {
  float: right;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #666;
  background: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="notification-message-unread"></div>
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if it explained what was happening and linked to documentation about the new properties and features used. As is it, its just a lump of code that is hard to learn from.

Comment: Here's a blinking border `box-shadow` based on this code: https://jsfiddle.net/btgjfq62

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use CSS keyframe animations.

```css
    .box {
      height: 500px;
      width: 500px;
      animation: animationFrames 5s infinite;
    }
    
    
    @keyframes animationFrames{
      0% {
        background-color: blue;
      }
      15% {
        background-color: red;
      }
      30% {
        background-color: orange;
      }
      45% {
        background-color: purple;
      }
      60% {
        background-color: green;
      }
      75% {
       background-color: pink;
      }
      100% {
        background-color: black;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

In the `.box` class I'm using the `animation` property to link to an animation keyframe called `animationFrames`. I'm also defining how long I want this animation to play for, in the example above it's `5s` and set to `infinite` so it repeats forever. The keyframe portion sets what CSS you want to apply to the animation at what percent in the animation, for example at 15% of 5 seconds it will turn red.

You can learn more about CSS keyframe animations [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp).

As per your specific example this code should work (I added a height property just so you could see it)

```css
.chat-window {
   float: right;
   font-size: 10px;
   color: #666;
   background: white;
   padding-left: 10px; 
   animation: animationFrames 2s infinite;
   height: 500px;
}
        
@keyframes animationFrames{
  50% {
   background-color: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-window"></div>
```